# C# profiler for Windows

Tags: windows, profiling

I am looking for C# profilers:

- Win 7 SP1 or later
- free to use for commercial use (the tools budget is 0)
- zip-deployment: nice to have

At this moment I'm using CodeTrack, but a tool with some memory profiling features would be more than welcome.

Comment: Which version of visual studio you are using 2013?professional? Ultimate?

Comment: @Gilad Visual Studio Professional 2017

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into profiling tools, command as part of the Performance tools 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/using-the-profiling-tools-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2017

Performance Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.0)

Answer (score 0):

## CodeTrack

http://www.getcodetrack.com/

- Wide support:

  - x64 and x86 architectures
  - .NET 2
  - .NET 4 and up
  - .NET Core
  - Standalone apps
  - Webservices, WCF, ASP.NET
  - IIS and IIS Express
  - Windows services
  - Including child processes
- Analysis

  - Detailed call information including generic arguments
  - Performance tree (per thread/process and combined)
  - **Unique timeline view**
  - **Flamegraph view**
  - List view
  - Heli view
  - Code view
  - Exceptions overview
  - Search & Mark features
  - Rescope & Filter threads
- Non invasive & portable:

  - Attach to a running process
  - **No installation required**, copy the files and you're ready to go!
  - Possibility for offline analysis on a different machine
- Free:

  - Best of all: CodeTrack is free to use!
  - You can use Codetrack for personal and commercial use
  - Please refer to the detailed license in the about window

... and many other nice features.